# React state undefined with useEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-dom

Getting the same (state) undefined error across multiple components. I've checked and seen that data does come from the API, isn't blocked by CORS or something, and is available to the useEffect callback. The problem seems to be in setting the state. I tried replacing the useState hook with the useRef hook and got the same result when accessing ref.current.

What's really weird, is, a couple of days ago everything worked fine, so I moved to work on the backend code to be greated today with a white screen.

The error, the familiar:

**Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "map", data is undefined**

**EDIT: Solution** - the TypeError was due to the actual type cast when the data payload structure changed.

*Dashboard.tsx* the index route.

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState<ServiceStatus[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    server.monitor.services()
      .then(data => setData(data))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Title order={2}>Dashboard</Title>
      <BackToTop />
      <div>
        <LoadingOverlay visible={loading} overlayBlur={2} />
        {data
          .map(svc => <ServiceStatusListItem key={svc.value?.ServiceName} status={svc} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

*server.ts*

```
export const server = {
  monitor: {
    services: async () => {
      const url = `${hostname}/Monitor/Services`;
      const statuses = await fetch(url, addAuthorization()).then(resp => resp.json());
      return statuses as ServiceStatus[];
    }
  }
};
```

Screenshots available at https://i.stack.imgur.com/76g2Z.jpg.

Comment: I know this seems quite obvious, but can you paste a screenshot of the data being returned in the dev tools network pane?

Comment: **I moved to work on the backend code to be greated today with a white screen** - your backend returns nothing as data

Comment: If the problem is by Cors you need install npm i cors

Comment: Add 1 sample response of API,

Comment: Indeed. Sounds like his API no longer gives an array so the cast assumption is not right.

Comment: Are you using node with express or Next.js?

Comment: @SebastianMelendez good question, I use react-dom

Comment: @vukovinski so, the problem is by Cors, I think you have the frontend and backend separate, so you need install cors.

import cors from "cors" // ESC6
app.use(cors()) // to ability the peticions of the other localhost or host

Comment: @AdamThomas sure, here are the screengrabs

https://imgur.com/a/Rbgi8Ba

Comment: @SebastianMelendez no, CORS is not the problem

Comment: Hmm its definitely weird. Could you put a `console.log(data)` just before `setData(data)` in the promise `then` callback -- and report what it is?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the jsx render till loading is completed, I'm assuming data array will have length greater than 0

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState<ServiceStatus[]>([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);
      server.monitor.services()
        .then(data => setData(data))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);
    if(loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
    return (
      <div>
        <Title order={2}>Dashboard</Title>
        <BackToTop />
        <div>
          <LoadingOverlay visible={loading} overlayBlur={2} />
          {data
            .map(svc => <ServiceStatusListItem key={svc.value?.ServiceName} status={svc} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It should be fine though, since his default state shape is already an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `data` is contains value = `undefined`
so you should check if it data contains some value other than so called falsy values, such as (NULL, undefined)

You can do this

```
{data?.map(svc => <ServiceStatusListItem key={svc.value?.ServiceName} status={svc} />)}
```

or

```
{if(data) {data.map(svc => <ServiceStatusListItem key={svc.value?.ServiceName} status={svc} />)}}
```

or

```
{data && data.map(svc => <ServiceStatusListItem key={svc.value?.ServiceName} status={svc} />)}
```

as you mentioned, something is wrong with useState
here something you should try

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    server.monitor.services()
      .then((data) => {setData(data)})
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

Comment: Yes, ofc, I tried this, but then nothing ever displays, seems like data is always undefined, which is wrong obviously since it is in scope of the function component

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to pause the execution until the Promise gets resolved, and you do this as following,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    
    const fetchStatuses = async () => {
      const res = await server.monitor.services()
      .then(data => setData(data))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      return res
    }

    fetchStatuses()
  }, []);
```

See this [link](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect), for more details about using async functions inside useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad and Adam were right, the changes to the backend did cause an error in when accessing and displaying the data.

> I moved to work on the backend code to be greated today with a white screen - your backend returns nothing as data

Modifying the server.ts fixed the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).